# How do you safely and efficiently get the row id after an insert with mysql using MySQLdb in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a simple table in mysql with the following fields:

- id -- Primary key, int, autoincrement
- name -- varchar(50)
- description -- varchar(256)

Using MySQLdb, a python module, I want to insert a name and description into the table, and get back the id.

In pseudocode:

```
db = MySQLdb.connection(...)
queryString = "INSERT into tablename (name, description) VALUES" % (a_name, a_desc);"

db.execute(queryString);
newID = ???
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get the IDENTITY / AUTONUMBER value for the row I inserted in pymysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802061/how-do-i-get-the-identity-autonumber-value-for-the-row-i-inserted-in-pymysql), which is a better Q&A pair; this one has a wrong answer accepted with the right answer edited in underneath, which is weird and unhelpful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it might be

```
newID = db.insert_id()
```

---

**Edit by Original Poster**

Turns out, in the version of MySQLdb that I am using (1.2.2)
You would do the following:

```
conn = MySQLdb(host...)

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO...")
newID = c.lastrowid
```

I am leaving this as the correct answer, since it got me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Do this *before* the commit, if you are not automatically commiting.

Comment: @kmarsh I know this comment is super old, but do you remember why it should be before the commit?

Comment: I guess because the code is done with the cursor, and will lose context after the commit. Shorter answer, it worked better for me that way.

Comment: what if we have a scenario where two concurrent processed inserted new records in db. What is the authenticity that it will return correct record id?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a MySQLdb specific API for this, but in general you can obtain the last inserted id by [SELECTing LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

It is on a per-connection basis, so you don't risk race conditions if some other client performs an insert as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a

`conn.insert_id`

Answer (score -8):

The easiest way of all is to wrap your insert with a select count query into a single stored procedure and call that in your code. You would pass in the parameters needed to the stored procedure and it would then select your row count.