# time complexity to get auto incremented row id in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-db-api

I am a newbie at mysql and databases.
I have a simple question. I have created a table that has an integer type id column that is auto incremented. After each insert I get the last row inserted id (in python using cursor.lastrowid, or connection.insert_id()). I wanted to know what is the time complexity in mysql to get this value?
I am guessing its O(1) as the database should be storing this value somewhere and updating it after each insert?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` that was created by the last `INSERT` statement of your session. So, probably MySQL stores the value somewhere for every session.

Comment: see SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/in-python-after-i-insert-into-mysqldb-how-do-i-get-the-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.lastrowid` will return the value from the single insert 
see: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

`connection.insert_id()` will have to make a seperate call to get the last_insert_id, and would slightly slower