# sql python - return sql variable

Tags: python, sql

I have SQL command something like this:

```
DEFINE item_id_variable
BEGIN
INSERT INTO items (name, value, status) 
    VALUES (myname, myvalue, mystatus) 
    RETURNING item_id INTO item_id_variable;
```

The table has auto-incrementing attribute item_id and it's value for the row I just added is in the item_id_variable. I trigger this with cursor.execute() and it works ok, but I need to read the value of "item_id_variable" into a python variable, so I can pass it further in the code.
How do I do that??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cursor.fetchall() (for example)?

Comment: If I try to fetch after that command it throws "cx_Oracle: InterfaceError: not a query".

Answer (score 0):

Read it [How do I get the "id" after INSERT into MySQL database with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/in-python-after-i-insert-into-mysqldb-how-do-i-get-the-id)

You can get the last insert id by "SELECT last_insert_id()" or connection.insert_id()

Comment: SELECT last_insert_id()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found while expected
;  Also tried:   
connection.insert_id()
AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Connection' object has no attribute 'insert_id'