# How to fetch the primary key from a table

Tags: python, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, after I INSERT Into mysqldb, how do I get the “id”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/in-python-after-i-insert-into-mysqldb-how-do-i-get-the-id)

How to fetch the primary key post insertion into foo, so that I can insert the foreign key reference in other tables.

```
import MySQLdb

cursor = mysqlconn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO foo (value) VALUES (%s)""", (value))
prod_mysql_conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as:

```
mysqlconn.insert_id()
```

or

```
cursor.lastrowid
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
  show index from table_name where Key_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

table_name is a table name. Have a look on the column_name field on the result, you will get that PRIMARY KEY column of the table.