# python mysqldb INSERT is inserting arbitrary values in AUTO_INCREMENT primary column

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a mysql database. I have a column named id which is also the primary key. I have inserted manually till 25. Now I have written a python code to insert into the database. The code for inserting is

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Website (website_name, enabled) VALUES (%s, 0)""", (store_name))
```

Now, the problem I am having is that the values in the auto_increment column are arbitrary. Like, the value inserted after 25 is 1116. Is there a way to insert them in increasing order?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `auto_increment` value by `lastrowid`

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Website (website_name, enabled) VALUES (%s, 0)""", (store_name))
my_last_id = c.lastrowid  # cursor.lastrowid
```

For further reference dive [How do I get the "id" after INSERT into MySQL database with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/in-python-after-i-insert-into-mysqldb-how-do-i-get-the-id)

Comment: I do not want the value. I want the value to be incremented in increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial requirement for a primary is that it has to be unique. There is no hard and fast requirement for a primary key to be perfectly sequential, or for that matter to even be consistently ascending.

If you have a requirement for a value that is consistently ascending and perfectly sequential, then good practice is to have a separate column (I.e. not the primary key column) to store the sequential values. You will need to set those values from within your code using a mechanism that takes into account concurrency issues if applicable.

With most database implementations, there is no explicit guarantee that auto-increment values will be perfectly sequential.