# Get the last inserted id in django

Tags: python, django, rawsql

I am migrating some data from other databases , so i am using raw sql queries for inserting data into database . But i don't know how to get last inserted id from raw sql queries in django. I have tried this

```
affected_count1=cursor2.execute("table')")

and

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘MyTable’)
```

but it gives me the error of **"(1305, 'FUNCTION pydev.SCOPE_IDENTITY does not exist')"**

So please tell me how can i get the last inserted id in raw sq l queries in django

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/in-python-after-i-insert-into-mysqldb-how-do-i-get-the-id

Comment: which db engine are you using?

Answer (score 31):

You can get latest create obj like this:

```
obj = Foo.objects.latest('id')
```

more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

Comment: No, this is unrelated to the question.

Comment: I know it is unrelated to the question: but whenever I try to add default=Foo.objects.latest('id') to a ForeignKey in a model; I get the error "App registry isn't ready yet." while launching. (Django 1.7a2); do you know why?

Comment: is latest, use concurrency ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
LastInsertId = (TableName.objects.last()).id
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `last().id` over using `.latest('id')`, as proposed in the top-voted answer?

Comment: .latest('id') Throwed an error :> TypeError: Object of type TableName is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 3):

In Django 1.6

```
obj = Foo.objects.latest('id')

obj = Foo.objects.earliest('id')
```