# How to return the last primary key after INSERT in pymysql (python3.5)?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

for example, how to get the primary key `id` of the last record that I insert into the table by `cursor.execute("insert into ...", ...)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python Perhaps this is what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the "id" after INSERT into MySQL database with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python)

Answer (score 7):

after inserting,You can get it as:
`cursor.execute('select LAST_INSERT_ID()')` or use `cursor.lastrowid`

Comment: ids = cursor.execute('select LAST_INSERT_ID()')

print(ids)


it just got `1`, not the last insert id!

Comment: try `cursor.lastrowid` .