# How to get primary key ID of two different tables to automatically insert in another table in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to get primary keys from table 1 (patient_id) & table 2 (assessor_id), and insert them automatically into table 3. My HTML code for table 3 isn't working since it requires primary keys from other tables. I have to input the values (i.e.: patient_id, and assessor_id) manually. Is there any ways to insert the primary key automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Or rather, actually you just need `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID after each `INSERT`. You should do all of this in a transaction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python

Comment: where should i add "select last insert id ()" @BaileyParker? i tried to replace it with "patient_id" but it doesn't work

Comment: Immediately after the first insert, just save `partient_id = cursor.lastrowid`. Then after the second save `assessor_id = cursor.lastrowid`. Then your final insert just works.

Comment: @BaileyParker I got this error after doing that: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'lastrowid'.

Comment: Then `g.db_conn.insert_id()`. Read the linked duplicates. They will help.

Comment: thanks, it works now :)