# How to fix a ‘nontype object is not subscriptable' error when doing fetchone() method in sql?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have written some SQL data, but when I want to do a fetchone()[0] method to extract the first value of the row, but it returns a traceback stating that "'nontype' object is not subscriptable". I just don't know how to fix that.

I have deleted the [0] part and the traceback disappears, but I need to extract the first value, so the [0] is kind of essential part.

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist(name) VALUES(?)''',(artist,))
cur.execute('''SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name=?''',(artist,))
artist_id=cur.fetchone()[0]
conn.commit()
```

I expect that I could fetch the first value of the extracted row, Which is the id.

Comment: If you are getting that error, `cur.fetchone()` is returning `None` instead of a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that `cur.fetchone()` returned `None`. This happens when the last select statement didn't yield any result (nothing matched the select statement).

So the question is "why didn't the select statement select anything when I just inserted something", and the answer is (well, most probably) that your [transaction's isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) prevents you from reading yet uncommited changes.

You could change the isolation level, but a simplest solution would be to first commit the transaction and only then try to read the data (IOW : move your `conn.commit()` statement between the "insert" and the "select").

But for this exact use case, you actually don't need the "select" query at all - [you can just retrieve the last insert id directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python).