# How to get id of newly created record -Postgresql-Flask?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a new row into `postgresql` database using `psycopg2` and `flask`.
Here is the code:

```
con = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=crm_whatsapp user=user_name password=user_password")
cur = con.cursor()
    create = cur.execute("INSERT INTO crm_user_chat_data (number) VALUES (%s) returning id",(user_number,)) //Here it returns none
con.commit()
```

But I am getting `None` instead of `id`.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve inserted id after inserting row in SQLite using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python)

Comment: @Marcin, i tried `lastrowid`, but it returns `0` always.

Comment: What about How do I get the “id” after INSERT into MySQL database with Python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch() from the cursor to get the id:

```
cur = con.cursor()
create = cur.execute("INSERT INTO crm_user_chat_data (number) VALUES (%s) returning id",(user_number,))
con.commit()    
insertId = cur.fetchone()
```