# Insert multi information for smae id

Tags: python, mysql, entity-relationship

How can i insert in MYSQL for one id multi - inputs as shown below : without repeating "vehicle code" as i activate auto increment

[image]

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have two [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model): **vehicle** and **tyre**. They have a many-to-many relationship to each other

So you need three tables.

```
vehicle:

vehicle_id(PK)   vehicle_no  vehicle_code
1                AST-001     V-01
2                BTU-001     Q-99

tyre:

tyre_id(PK)  size   pattern (size and pattern are part of a UNIQUE key)
1            AB     BB
2            AC     CC
3            AD     XX
4            AE     YY
5            AF     ZZ
6            AG     AA
7            PA     R1

vehicle_tyre:  (to handle the many-to-many relationship)

vehicle_id  tyre_id  tyre_no   (all columns are part of a composite primary key)
1           1         1
1           2         2
1           3         3
1           4         4
1           5         5
1           6         6
2           1         7    (this vehicle has four tyres, all the same)
2           2         7
2           3         7
2           4         7
```

When your app has a new type of tyre to insert you do this. The IGNORE together with the UNIQUE index on `(size, pattern)` prevents the insertion of duplicate tyres without lots of extra work.

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO tyre (size, pattern) VALUES (?, ?);  #[size, pattern]
```

When you hae a new vehicle to insert you do this. You run the following three SQL statements, and repeat the last one for each tyre on the vehicle.

```sql
INSERT INTO vehicle (vehicle_no, vehicle_code) VALUES (?,?);  #[no, code]
SET @vehicle_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO vehicle_tyre (vehicle_id, tyre_id, tyre_no)
             SELECT       @vehicle_id, tyre_id, ?
               FROM tyre
              WHERE size = ? AND pattern = ?;   #[tyre_no, size, pattern]
```

[LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is the trick to getting the vehicle_id right in the vehicle_tyre table. Notice this: after you do an INSERT with python, you can get the LAST_INSERT_ID() value using `cursor.lastrowid` or `connection.insert_id()`. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python)

Comment: Thanks for your help !, i'll try it and feedback !