# Pyodbc: how can I get the primary key after a successful insert into the SQL Server database?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a table `Employee` in SQL Server as follows:

```
ID (AUTO, PK),
firstname (varchar),
lastname (varchar)
```

I want to insert data like `('John', 'Myers')` into the table.

I used the following code in Python using pyodbc:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into employee(firstname, lastname) values(?, ?)", ['John','Myers'])
```

Is it possible to get the `ID` value of this newly inserted row without having to write a `select` query?

Comment: This one may help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python

Comment: Check this out - https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions/1162

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `OUTPUT` clause

```
cursor.execute("insert into employee(firstname, lastname) output inserted.ID values(?, ?);", ['John','Myers'])
id = cursor.fetchone()
```

Alternatively, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
cursor.execute("insert into employee(firstname, lastname) values(?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", ['John','Myers'])
id = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, however, in my case, the value is returned into id, but the inserted record does NOT show up in the table. Please advise!

Comment: Sounds like you have `autocommit=false` (ie `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`) or you have an explicit transaction which you are not committing