# How do I insert Lists in python into a SQL Table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have to do some work with a SQL Database. I have done a bit of research on with video but I got very confused
Could you please explain to me how I insert python lists index into a SQL database?

I'm trying to make the Location a foreign key from its own table. This will allow for easier access in the future so that I can call all the cities from one country with a WHERE statement. I'm doing this so that I can scale this in the future to something else but I want to know how to do it with this example.

LocationID  -   United Kingdom = 1 France = 2 Denmark = 3 Germany = 4

Place:
London + LocationID1

This is how I want it to look.

This is what I have so far:

```
import sqlite3
Location = ["United Kingdom","Germany","France","Denmark"]
Places = ["London","Tottenham","Munich","Paris","Frankfurt"]

conn = sqlite3.connect("Location.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO Places Location[0])
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This returns an error for me
I don't know if I need to provide the database file. Just ask me if you need it to assist me

Comment: The syntax of `INSERT` is `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (col1Value, col2Value, ...)`

Comment: Use query parameters. See https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-bind-variables-to-a-sql-query-in-sqlite3-in-python

Comment: I'll try that now. Do you have any idea, how I can link the IDs from Location into the Places table

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python

Comment: Thank you, I'll look over the link now

Comment: @Barmar Could you explain how .lastrowid works?

Comment: After you insert into a table that uses `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `cursor.lastrowid` will contain the ID that was assigned to that row. So after you insert `United Kingdom` into the `Location` table, `cursor.lastrowid` will contain its ID. Save that in a variable and use it when inserting all the UK cities into the `Places` table.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I'm starting to understand this now

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.