# How do I get the IDENTITY / AUTONUMBER value for the row I inserted in pymysql

Tags: python, mysql

Is possible to get ID for the row I inserted using pymysql?

```
curr = db.cursor()
curr.execute("INSERT INTO `accounts` (`name`, `password`) VALUES ('%s', '%s')", accName, passwd)
curr.execute("INSERT INTO `person` (`name`, `accoiunt_id`) VALUES ('%s', '%d')", pName, HERE_I_NEED_ACCID)
```

There is autoincrement primary key "id" in accounts table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you safely and efficiently get the row id after an insert with mysql using MySQLdb in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706755/how-do-you-safely-and-efficiently-get-the-row-id-after-an-insert-with-mysql-usin)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `lastrowid` property of your cursor object.

Or you can execute [`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), and fetch the result as scalar with `fetchone()`