# How to get primary_key of last inserted record in database with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to add some data to database using python. But I'm unable to get the auto increment `primary_key` of the last inserted record.

I've checked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548493/how-do-i-get-the-id-after-insert-into-mysql-database-with-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706755/how-do-you-safely-and-efficiently-get-the-row-id-after-an-insert-with-mysql-usin), but it haven't worked.

My code is as follows:

```
def insert_vehicles_to_db(vehicle):
    conn = db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()    

    if vehicle_not_exists(vehicle, conn, cur):
        try:
            insert_vehicle(vehicle, conn, cur)
        except Exception as e:
            pass    
    else:
        pass
    conn.close()
```

Then it goes to `insert_vehicle` function. In that function I want:

- to add a new `vehicle` to the database
- to add a new price in `vehicle_price` table
- for previous step I need the last inserted vehicle primary key from `vehicles` table

The function `insert_vehicle` is as follows:

```
def insert_vehicle(vehicle, conn, cur):
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO vehicles (reference, data, price, reference_url, timestamp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
        cur.execute(query, (vehicle['reference'], "", vehicle['price'], vehicle['reference_url'], datetime.datetime.now()))


        ////////// I tried here vehicle_id = cur.lastrowid, it gives me always 0 //////////


        insert_vehicle_price(vehicle['price'], vehicle_id, conn, cur)
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        # TODO Handle error
        pass
```

And `insert_vehicle_price` looks as follows:

```
def insert_vehicle_price(price, vehicle_id, conn, cur):
    //// Here I need the correct vehicle_id to be able to insert a new record in `vehicle_price` table
    pass
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: if I were you I've probably finished writing this using SQLAlchemy ORM

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE vehicles` in the mysql client, and include the result in your question. To confirm that the table actually has an auto-increment PK, and which column is it.

Comment: @BillKarwin I get an error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 1: SHOW CREATE TABLE vehicles
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 6`

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:mysql]. But that error format indicates you are using PostgreSQL, not MySQL. That could explain why the `lastrowid` doesn't behave as you think it should.

Comment: That is true. Any idea how to do it with postgresql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247685/python-postgres-psycopg2-getting-id-of-row-just-inserted

Answer (score 3):

In case your primary_key is the ID then you can use `cursor.lastrowid` to get the last row ID inserted on the cursor object, or `connection.insert_id()` to get the ID from the last insert on that connection.